# Android: Spinner does not update after change of dataset

Tags: android, spinner, adapter, android-contentprovider, loader

In my app the spinne shows the active items (I use Loader of support library to load them). The init of spinner works fine and it shows only the active items.

But I got the followeing problem:
When I edit the items in another activity and store them (active and deactivat some of them) an go back (Back-Button), then I see the "old" list of items in the spinner. The adapter get the new cursor with correct data, but the spinner does not refresh his list.

What can I do to refresh the spinner list?

In `onCreate()` I initialize the Spinner

```
_ItemSpinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spn_itemss);
_ItemAdapter = new AdvancedCursorAdapter(
    getActivity(),
    R.layout.spinner_2line_item,
    null, _ColumnList, _ColumnViews, 0);
_ItemSpinner.setAdapter(_ItemAdapter);
```

In `onResume()` I start the loader initialisation

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
    super.onStart();
}
```

In `onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)` I swap the cursor for the adapter

```
_ItemAdapter.swapCursor(data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out, not why, but which, element ***destroy*** the refresh of the spinner.

I used two different URIs of the same ContentProvider for updating all items and showing only active items

1. CONTENT_URI_ITEMS
2. CONTENT_URI_ACTIVE_ITEMS

If I use the same URI for updating and showing (with needed active filter), the spinner list will be updated. If I use different URIs, the spinner shows ***old*** data.

I don't understand this behavior (the cursor returns correct number of items, but the spinner doesn't care), but I have a work around that works.

Store data:

```
getActivity().getContentResolver().update(
    RecordsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_ITEMS,
    _Changes,
    COLUMN_ID + " =?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(_ID) });
```

Before (get data) - **doesn't work**:

```
CursorLoader curLoader = new CursorLoader(this.getActivity(),
    RecordsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_ACTIVE_ITEMS,
    _ITEMS_PROJECTION,
    null, null, null);
```

After (get data) - **work**:

```
CursorLoader curLoader = new CursorLoader(this.getActivity(),
    RecordsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_ITEMS,
    _ITEMS_PROJECTION,
    COLUMN_IS_ACTIVE + " =1", null, null);
```

`notifyDataSetChanged` is not necessary, if the underlying `ContentProvider` do this for you like this: (`getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);`)

Answer (score 3):

you can call the adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged` method

Comment: well I was answering "what can I do" :-)

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't help. The spinner shows _**old**_ data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
```

in your activity, just after making changes on a database.