# Spinner values not getting updated onRestart()

Tags: android

I have a spinner in the page which takes values from database. If I proceed to the next page and then press a back button I land on the page containing spinner. While I am on the other page and my db gets updated I want to reflect it on the spinner as soon as I go back to the page containing the spinner.
I am using php mysql for db connections.
What I have used is:

```
public void onRestart(){
     super.onRestart();
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Where adapter is the array adapter that sets the spinner value.
I have written this code on the page containing the spinner.

The above code doesn't update the spinner.... Please help....

Comment: what you done to get the latest values on the other page? Probably you should do the same to update the spinner containing page. Simply adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); alone wont help you. You should add the value to the list.

Answer (score 0):

try On Resume like this

```
public void onResume(){
     super.onResume();
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

hope it will help

**EDIT**

If it doesn't help try logging the onresume()

and i guess the problem is about adapter, you suppose to refresh the adapter.

i google documentation about **notifyDataSetChanged() : Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself**.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721937/android-spinner-does-not-update-after-change-of-dataset) to same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
Using handler you can update the data frquently


final Handler handler = new Handler()
    handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            handler.postDelayed( this, 60 * 1000 );
        }
    }, 60 * 1000 );
```

It's my full activity its works fine

```
package com.androidhive.dashboard;



import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidhive.dashboard.R;

public class EventActivity extends Activity
{
    Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
    InternetConnection cd;
    public EditText uname,pwd;
    public Button btnlog1,btncancel1;
    public boolean connect=false,logged=false;
    public String db_select;
     String mUname;
    ListView l1,l2;
    Spinner s;
    public Iterator<String> itr,itr1;
    private final String SERVICE_URL =  AddIp.Address+"/Events";
    private final String TAG = "Event";
    ArrayList<String> todoItems,cad;
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa,a1;

    public List<String> list1=new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<String> list12=new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events);
         l1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
         l2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);
         todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
         cad=new ArrayList<String>();
            aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.mylist,R.id.list_content,todoItems);
            l1.setAdapter(aa);
            a1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.mylist,R.id.list_content,cad);
            l2.setAdapter(a1);


                todoItems.clear();
                cad.clear();
                cd = new InternetConnection(getApplicationContext());
                 isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                 if (isInternetPresent)
                    {
                    try
                    {
                        validat_user();
                        final Handler handler = new Handler()
                    handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    validat_user();
                    handler.postDelayed( this, 60 * 1000 );
                    }
                    }, 60 * 1000 );

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        display("Network error.\nPlease check with your network settings.");

                    }
                    }
                 else
                 {
                     display("No Internet Connection");
                 }


    }
    public void display(String msg)
    {
        Toast.makeText(EventActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    private void validat_user()
    {

        WebServiceTask wst = new WebServiceTask(WebServiceTask.POST_TASK, this, "Authentication in progress...");


       // wst.addNameValuePair("Emp_PWD", stg2);
        //db_select="";
        wst.execute(new String[] { SERVICE_URL });

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void no_net()
    {
        display( "No Network Connection");
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(EventActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("No Internet Connection");
        alertDialog.setMessage("You don't have internet connection.\nElse please check the Internet Connection Settings.");
        //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.error_info);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                alertDialog.cancel();
                EventActivity.this.finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setButton2("Use Local DataBase", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                display( "Accessing local DataBase.....");
                alertDialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private class WebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        public static final int POST_TASK = 1;

        private static final String TAG = "WebServiceTask";

        // connection timeout, in milliseconds (waiting to connect)
        private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT = 3000;

        // socket timeout, in milliseconds (waiting for data)
        private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000;

        private int taskType = POST_TASK;
        private Context mContext = null;


        private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();



        public WebServiceTask(int taskType, Context mContext, String processMessage) {

            this.taskType = taskType;
            this.mContext = mContext;

        }

        public void addNameValuePair(String name, String value) {

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
        }


        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String url = urls[0];
            String result = "";

            HttpResponse response = doResponse(url);

            if (response == null) {
                return result;
            } else {

                try {

                    result = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());

                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                }

            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

            handleResponse(response);


        }

        // Establish connection and socket (data retrieval) timeouts
        private HttpParams getHttpParams() {

            HttpParams htpp = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(htpp, CONN_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(htpp, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

            return htpp;
        }

        private HttpResponse doResponse(String url) {

            // Use our connection and data timeouts as parameters for our
            // DefaultHttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParams());

            HttpResponse response = null;

            try {
                switch (taskType) {

                case POST_TASK:
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                    // Add parameters
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                display("Remote DataBase can not be connected.\nPlease check network connection.");

                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
                return null;

            }

            return response;
        }

        private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {

            String line = "";
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

            // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {
                // Read response until the end
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            }

            // Return full string
            return total.toString();
        }

    }
    public void handleResponse(String response)
    {    //display("JSON responce is : "+response);
        try {

            JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(response);


                  String UName = "hi";

                  if( UName.equalsIgnoreCase("") || UName==null)
                  {
                     display("Project report(s) can not be retrieved.");
                  }
                  else
                  {
//                     int count=Integer.parseInt(UName);
//                     display("Number of Projects have been handling in AFL right now: "+count);
                    list1=new ArrayList<String>();
                    list12=new ArrayList<String>();
                    JSONArray array=jso.getJSONArray("sun");
                    JSONArray array1=jso.getJSONArray("sun1");
                    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
                    {
                        list1.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("branchName1"));
                        list12.add(array1.getJSONObject(i).getString("branchName2"));

                    }
                    itr=list1.iterator();
                    itr1=list12.iterator();
                    while(itr.hasNext()&&itr1.hasNext())
                    {
                         //str1=itr.next()+"\n";
                        todoItems.add(0, itr.next().toString());
                        cad.add(0, itr1.next().toString());
                        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        a1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    //tv1.setText(str1);


                  }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            return;
        }

    }

}
```